# Can access modifiers be placed on the method declarations in an interface?

Tags: c#

if yes then why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, they can't. All functions defined in an interface have to be public (or what would the point of them being defined in an interface?).

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx):

> Interface members are always public because the purpose of an interface is to enable other types to access a class or struct. No access modifiers can be applied to interface members.

Answer (score 3):

An interface methods are, by definition, always public. To answer "why" consider that an interface is some kind of contract between two or more systems that use the same interface (either inside the same application or between applications, systems or networks).

To be able to share, means the methods must be public, otherwise the other class could never access them.

However, do note that *an interface as a whole can be `private`, `protected`, `internal`, `protected internal` or `public`*. Where private means that it is only available in its current scope (i.e., within a containing class for instance). The following is valid:

```
class SomeClass
{
    // inside a class, an interface can have access modifiers
    private interface IPrivateTest
    { 
        void TestMe();    // always public, cannot even use "public" keyword
    }    
}
```

Comment: There are situations where it would be useful for an assembly Foo to be able to declare an interface with "internal" members, such that assembly Foo can create class instances that implement the interface, pass them to outside code, and receive them back from outside code, without the outside code being able to substitute any type not provided by Foo.  It would be possible for Foo to define an interface which inherits from a public interface, have the outside world use the public interface, and cast things received from the outside world to the private interface, but that would provide...

Comment: ...only run-time rather than compile-time validation of the interface types.  The mechanisms may not exist in .net to allow such restrictions to be put on interfaces, but that doesn't mean they wouldn't be useful.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are always public.

Comment: And what about the "why"? ;-)

Comment: Sorry, the why appeared to be attached if the answer was 'yes'.

Answer (score 1):

No, access modifiers are defined for implementations for methods. An interface defines the **public** (or consumable) contract required for implementation, so those implemented methods must be public (unless they are declared explicitly).